# Should I take a loss or gain on stocks that can go either way? Is there a ruling on this?

Tags: taxes

In 2010, I bought  5 shares @ $20/share for $100.

In 2011, I bought 20 shares @ $5 for $100.

In 2018, I sold 10 shares @ $10 for a total of $100.

The other 15 shares, I hold indefinitely. How much taxes do I owe for this year?

Comment: The usual rule is first in first out: you sell the 5@20 first, then 5@5. However, you seem to have bought 25 shares total... where did the other five go?

Comment: @Peter K.  I think that you misread the question

Comment: Is this a homework question? What happened to the other 5 shares? And the text has nothing to do with the title!!!

Comment: Please add a location tag as it is important. (Seemingly in the US you can choose LIFO or FIFO; in the UK they are regarded as indistinguishable and you have to use an average cost basis. Other countries: I have no idea). And can I have the 5 missing shares?

Comment: @BobBaerker Why do you say that: `bought 5 shares` then `bought 20 shares` which means they have 25 shares, but then `sold 10 shares` and `The other 10 shares`  which is 20 shares. Where did the other five shares go? I think you misread my comment?

Comment: Did you edit your initial comment?  If not, then I misread it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to hold the last 15 shares indefinitely.  The FIFO rule pretty much answers my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the U.S., when you sell a portion of your holdings you can elect to choose which shares you want sold.  FIFO stands for First In, First Out.  LIFO stands for Last In, First Out.

Your broker must have an online process for share verification or you must obtain written confirmation from your broker that verifies the method chosen. Without such verification, the IRS will conclude that you never made an election and will default to the FIFO method.